# Tem como mascarar a URL de suas imagens do wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Quando passo o mouse em cima de algum arquivo ele me mostra o caminho completo do meu site.

Ex : http://localhost/portal/wp-content/uploads/sites/28/2015/04/web.jpg

Tem como esconder esse caminho quando clicar com botão dir do mouse em cima da imagem ?

Comment: Já tentou criar uma regra no `.htaccess` para apontar a parti de uma pasta? Assim sua *URL* ficaria mais curta. Exemplo: `http://localhost/portal/28/2015/04/web.jpg` estaria faendo um redirect para `wp-content/uploads/sites/`

Comment: Ainda não, você sabe qual a regra para aplicar no .htaccess ?  é multi site

Comment: [parte 1](http://drgeek.com.br/2013/tutorial-como-usar-htaccess-parte-1-o-que-e-htaccess/). [parte 2](http://drgeek.com.br/2013/tutorial-como-usar-htaccess-parte-2-habilitando-e-configurando-o-mod_rewrite/).  [parte 3](http://drgeek.com.br/2013/tutorial-como-usar-htaccess-parte-3-paginas-de-erro-personalizadas/). [parte 4](http://drgeek.com.br/2013/tutorial-como-usar-htaccess-parte-4-definindo-a-index-page-e-evitando-a-listagem-de-diretorio/). Nestes links vc vai aprender todo o necessário pra trabalhar com `.htaccess`